# Is there a mechanism to filter common nouns from a bag of nouns?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, linguistics

`"the bride and the groom got married at the church."`

Applying a simple POS-tagger on the above sentence yields:

`"the bride(NOUN) and the groom(NOUN) got married at the church(NOUN)."`

I am interested in filtering out `bride, groom`. I have tried using various NLP tricks like NER (extracting noun-phrases) but in vain.

I would like to know if this problem is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured that I can use [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) for the same task.